# How can I get the public IP of the sender of a HTTP request ? NodeJS (express)

Tags: node.js, express, http, ip-address

I'm trying to get the public IP of a HTTP request sender on a NodeJS server.
I tried with:
`req.socket.remoteAddress`
`req.connection.remoteAddress` ...

But these lines gives me the local address of the server.

Comment: "But these lines gives me the local address of the server." How? Do you have a reverse proxy on the server running? Explain how your app is hosted/accessible. Provide more details.

Comment: For example, if my public ip is 1.2.3.4
When I call my API, I want it to get my IP address (1.2.3.4), and not 127.0.0.1
req.socket.remoteAddress and req.connection.remoteAddress both returns 127.0.0.1

Comment: I dont have any proxy running. Just a simple express server.

Comment: You comment is confusing. You want the Server public ip or the client source ip? When you get "127.0.0.1" as socket address, that means the request that reaches express is from your own server, which is only possible when you run a nginx/apache as reverse proxy in front of your app. Please edit your question and add more details! Also i highly recond me you to  complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It seems pretty clear for me ^^ 
I want the public ip address of the user that calls the request

Comment: Depending on the flow of data, you will have to use the data in `x-forwarded-for`.  That's the only chain of information that could potentially lead you to the right data. If that header's not there, then req.ip/req.connection.remoteAddress.

Comment: but this header can be edited by hand. I dont want to use it because of it. I want to be sure 100% to get the right IP address.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `req.ip` in express, the docs https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.ip

Comment: It is the same as req.connection.remoteAddress...
What I want is to get the public IP address of the user that sends the request. The same ip address as the one inside the header 'x-forwarded-for'. But I dont want to use this header, because I can be modified easily.